# div that shows only on android

Tags: android, css, html5-video, jwplayer

is it possible to have a div tag that is visible only in specific devices?

We have a video page that has HTML5 fallback that plays well on desktop and iOS devices but not on Android (specifically samsung S3)

I did some research and the probable reason behind it is that .m3u8 is not fully supported in android and RTSP has more success reports.

I'd like to put a div tags under our video embed code that will only show on android devices.

Something like...

```
<div id="androids"><a href="rtsp_url">Android user please click here to watch video</a></div>
```

Is this possible?

By the way. i am using JW Player on my page.

Thanks

Comment: To answer your question, is it possible? Yes. Use JavaScript to detect device and based on that show/hide video and show/hide div for android.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="video"></div>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
var ua = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
var isAndroid = ua.indexOf('android') > -1;

var videoDiv = document.getElementById('video'); 

if(isAndroid) {
  videoDiv.innerHTML = '<a href="rtsp_url">Android user please click here to watch video</a>';
} else {
  //add something else
  videoDiv.innerHTML = '<video>This is HTML 5 video for non-Android users</video>';
}
```

To explain: JavaScript finds out if user use Android or not. If users use Android it adds `<a href="rtsp_url">Android user please click here to watch video</a>` to `<div id="video">`, if not it adds regular HTML 5 `<video>` tag.

***Note:*** Instead of `<video>This is HTML 5 video for non-Android users</video>` add your video code.

Comment: this looks like it will work. I can't wait to try it. When I get back home I will try and report back. Thanks for the nice idea

Answer (score 0):

If you can use JavaScript, you could use `navigator.userAgent` to try and determine if it is a mobile browser and an Android device, and inject the appropriate HTML element.

Here's an example Android UA string:
`Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.0.2; en-us; Galaxy Nexus Build/ICL53F) AppleWebKit/534.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/534.30`

Answer (score 0):

if you use php,you could use this：

```
function isMobile(){
$useragent_commentsblock=preg_match(’|\(.*?\)|’,$useragent,$matches)>0?$matches[0]:”;

function CheckSubstrs($substrs,$text)
{
foreach($substrs as $substr)
if(false!==strpos($text,$substr))
return true;
return false;
}

$mobile_os_list=array(’Google Wireless Transcoder’,'Windows CE’,'WindowsCE’,'Symbian’,'Android’,'armv6l’,'armv5′,’Mobile’,'CentOS’,'mowser’,'AvantGo’,'Opera Mobi’,'J2ME/MIDP’,'Smartphone’,'Go.Web’,'Palm’,'iPAQ’);

$found_mobile=CheckSubstrs($mobile_os_list,$useragent_commentsblock);

if ($found_mobile) return true;
else return false;

}
```

if you only want android display ,can edit $mobile_os_list this arry。